# mySQL INSERT INTO no errors

Tags: php, mysql

```
$betadd = $user_data['bets'] + 1;
$username = $user_data['username'];
$userid = $user_data['user_id'];
$value = $_POST['wager'];
$setcoins = $user_data['coins'] -       $value;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `multiplayer` (value, player1) VALUES ($value, $username)");
```

I had it inserting into the table at one point, but now it doesn't work, Value is an INT (11) and player1 is a VARCHAR(32). But it doesn't insert into the columns, can anyone help?

Comment: Please see the manual page for [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) for examples about how to read error messages.

Comment: try to set your VALUES -always- in single/double quotes (depending your outer closures), even if they are numbers or ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to encapsulate your variables and to **debug** your query by doing

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `multiplayer` (value, player1) VALUES ('$value', '$username')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Then I  would like to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and indeed you are at risk of `sql injection`, have a look here [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You should use prepared statment to avoid any risk

Comment: Using "prepared statements" with place holders for parameters, also has the advantage of proper escaping of single quote, newline, backslash and so on.

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `multiplayer` (value, player1) VALUES ($value, $username)");
```

to this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `multiplayer` (value, player1) VALUES ('{$value}', '{$username)}'");
```

you need to add quotes to your values when you add it to db.. also I would suggest you look into PDO or mysqli .. mysql_query is deprecated and is not safe..

Dins